# Remove single quote in unix script only when it is not an apostrophe

Tags: bash, unix

I want to keep ' in a sentence if they are used as i'll, it's etc. however need to remove 'wamp', 'etc'.

```
I'll say 'bash is great!' if I could do this
```

should become

```
I'll say bash is great! if I could do this.
```

Comment: What are the specs/conditions ??? Seems too tricky

Comment: I need the solution in bash.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried a few but nothing seems to work: sed "s/^'//; s/'$//" < test > test2

Comment: sed is not bash, I gave you a solution using perl

Comment: Why is sed ok but perl isn't?

Comment: It's actually **very** hard to remove quotes and preserve apostrophes in _all_ cases because an apostrophe occurs at the end of the possessive form of words ending in `s`. Also, some abbreviations in English _start_ with an apostrophe.

Comment: perl is not available on the server I am working on. It will be a nightmare to get this installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -pe "s@(?:\s'|'\s)@ @g" <<< "I'll say 'bash is great' if I could do this"
I'll say bash is great if I could do this
```

I remove `'` if this character is followed or preceded by a space. Dunno if it fit your needs or not (?!)

Comment: You could use perl in a bash script !

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping ' character. Usually in most languages and systems backslash \ is used for escaping special characters.

Try following:

```bash
> echo i'll say                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
i ll say                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
> echo i\'ll say                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
i'll say                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
> echo i\'ll say 'bash' is great                                                                                                                                                                                                 
i'll say bash is great                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> echo i\'ll say 'bash is great                                                                                                                                                                                                  
i'll say bash is great
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)* and [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    line="${line//\' / }"
    line="${line// \'/ }"
    line="${line//\',/,}"
    echo "$line"
done < YOUR_BIG_FILE.TXT
```

Comment: This works mostlt but have a small issue. I have a big text file that I need to clean up and get rid of quotes (not the apostrophes). If I have a line that begins with a quote, it is not getting removed.

Comment: @Shanthi: You should have mentioned that you want to process a big text file in the question. Using pure bash parameter expansion to do this is ok for small strings, but it's not really suitable for processing large amounts of text. It'd be much better to use sed (or perl or python).